# Is it possible to use Unification for lambda calculus?

Tags: lambda-calculus, unification

[Unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)) is an algorithmic process of solving equations between symbolic expressions.

I have solved a few execercises in FOL: `f(x,b()) = f(a(),y) has one unifier: [a()/x,b()/y],`

Is it possible to use Unification for Lambda Calculus terms?

For example (= means beta reduces to):

Equation: `(λx.T) b = a b`. Solve for `T`

Solution: `[(a x)/T]`.

Verification: `((λx.T) b) [(a x)/T] = (λx.a x) b = a b`

I have also found that [Gérard Huet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A9rard_Huet) created unification algorithm for simply typed lambda calculus. I have just started learning and would appreciate any hint.

Comment: I haven't though this through, but I think the answer is yes, but that the unification algorithm may not terminate, and that determining if it terminates for a particular case is as difficult as the general halting problem.  Usually the thing we like about unification algorithms is that they always terminate, because they do structural recursion on the input term.

Comment: @MJD can you please provide a hint of how to think about Unification for Lambda Calculus? When I solve FOL exercises there always limited set of functions: in my post {f, a, b}, in group theory {binary_operation, inverse},... In Lambda Calculus there is infinite set of functions: {λx.x, λx.x+1,..}

Comment: unification is a very basic concept in lambda calculus. https://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/ar/slides11.pdf